# Why aren't Car Mods showing in Mod Dealer?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

I'm running ATS Utah. [As you can see](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/361889/231589), I activated these Mods: [Mercedes Benz SLK 55 AMG ATS 1.35+ Mod ATS](http://www.modsats.com/mercedes-benz-slk-55-amg-ats-1-35-mod-ats), [Mercedes X-Class 2018 ATS V1.0 1.35+ CAR](http://www.modsats.com/mercedes-benz-x-class-2018-ats-v1-0-1-35-car/), [Volkswagen Amarok V1R20 1.36.X CAR](http://www.modsats.com/ats-volkswagen-amarok-v1r20-1-36-x-car/). 
But why doesn't the Mod Dealer show them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the modification may not be standalone, it can only replace the truck. When you have three active modifications, they can cause errors. Deselect these three cars in modifications and check them one by one. It is worth adding that the modifications from version 1.35 may not work in version 1.36.